# Converting date and time to Millisecond Format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column containing the date and time, and I want to convert these column to be "yyyy-mm-dd -hh.mm.ss.nnnn"

My data as follow:

| POST_DATE | TRX_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 | 112029 |
| 2022-03-03 | 114143 |

The format that I want is as follows
"2022-02-23 -09.53.00.000"

I've searched and tried to modify my data using the following query

```
Select post_date, trx_time
    , convert(varchar, cast(post_date as varchar)+'-'+trx_time,114) 'hh:mi:ss:mmm'
from stg_trx_cz
```

and the result is I can't get the millisecond.

Is it possible with the data I have I can make the same format with the example?

Comment: Formatting is normally a front end job but did you try `FORMAT`? And what do you get when you change 114 to 121? (as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

Comment: Did you try a simple  `dateAdd(ms, trx_time, postDate)`? That would return a datetime value.

Comment: Be careful here. You are converting to varchar but you didn't specify the scale. Not sure why you have both cast and convert in the same column here. And why not convert to datetime or datetime2. Seems like maybe the real issue here is that you chose poorly when deciding on datatypes to use in your table.

Answer (score 3):

Generally when working with datetimes, it is *highly recommended* to use native data types as it makes everything else easier i.e. formatting.

So first I'd convert it to a datetime2(3) and then just call the `FORMAT()` function

### Formatting Datetime with Milliseconds

```
DECLARE @Post_Date DATE = '2022-03-03'
    ,@TRX_TIME VARCHAR(10) = '112029'

/*First convert to actual datetime*/
DECLARE @ActualDateTime DATETIME2(3) = (SELECT CAST(CONCAT(@Post_Date,' ',STUFF(STUFF(@TRX_TIME,3,0,':'),6,0,':')) AS DATETIME2(3)))

/*Then format*/
SELECT FORMAT(@ActualDateTime,'yyyy-MM-dd -hh.mm.ss.fff')
```